# What is the exponential form of Phase Shift Gate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin, quantum-computer

The Phase shift Gate is

$$R(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix}  1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\theta} \end{pmatrix} $$

Moreover,

$$R^{\dagger}(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0 & e^{-i\theta}\end{pmatrix} $$

Then,

$$R(\theta) R^{\dagger}(\theta) = R^{\dagger}(\theta)R(\theta) = I  $$

Therefore, $R(\theta)$ is unitary. Then, by Stone's Theorem,
$R(\theta)$ can be written as $R(\theta) = e^{iH}$, where  $H$ is a Hermitian matrix.

My question is, what is the exponential form $e^{iH}$ for $R(\theta)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$H=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&\theta\end{pmatrix}.$$

It's easy to exponentiate $iH$ and check that it works.

Answer (score 0):

And if you're wondering how to get to @G.Smith's answer, do a Taylor Expansion of $R(\theta)$. A slightly more instructive way to write what you call "[Stone's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups)" is that:

$$R(\theta) = e^{i\theta H},$$ where $\theta$ is variable that parametrises the group elements, and $H$ is the Hermitian generator.

Now imagine you're looking at a very small deviation from the identity: $$R(\theta) = e^{i\theta H} \quad \implies \quad R(\theta) = \mathbb{I} + i \theta H  - \frac{\theta^2 H^2}{2}\quad+\quad ...$$

On the other hand, if you expand the form of $R(\theta)$ (which basically boils down to writing the exponential term as a series),  you have $$R(\theta) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\theta}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & i\theta\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & -\frac{\theta^2}{2}\end{pmatrix}+\quad...$$

Now, these two terms must be equal for arbitrary $\theta$, and so comparing powers of $\theta$, you can see that $$H = \begin{pmatrix}0 &0 \\ 0& 1 \end{pmatrix},$$ and so

$$R(\theta) = e^{i \theta H}.$$